# can't see whole dropdown-menu on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu

I can't see the whole menu because the screen is to small, and I have tried to use the code "overflow:scroll" but i think i just keep scroll the page (one-pager) and not scrolling the menu.
http://19.pswebb.se/varbergstaxi/

Answer (score 0):

At 40px font size, your menu items are pretty large. At 20px your menu items would still be readable, and fit on most screens.
Something like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   #mobil ul li {
     line-height: 1.25;
   }
   #mobil a {
     font-size: 20px;
     line-height: 2.25;
   } }
```